# Formula for pressure using this equation for force

Tags: classical-mechanics, pressure

I have for a plane surface the following equation for force.

$$F(x)=b \rho lxg$$

Where the force moving along the $y$ coordinate doesn’t change. I need to calculate the pressure in an area in the surface bounded by a rectangle of length $x_2-x_1$ and base $b$. I tried doing the following procedure to figure out what the pressure is and I would like to know if it is correct, and if not what mistake have I done. The problem is the following: I need to find the pressure in that area. If the force would be a constant $F$ then the pressure would simply be:

$$P= \frac{F}{A} $$

However since the force varies along the $x$ coordinate then another way to calculate the pressure is required. First of all we do the following substitution.

$$\sigma =1/P $$

So then we have the following expression.

$$d \sigma = \frac{dA}{F(x)} $$

Integrating other sides we get the following expression.

$$\int d\sigma =\int \frac{bdx}{F(x)} = \frac{1}{\rho lg}ln(\frac{h+l}{h})$$

Therefore:

$$P=\frac{\rho lg}{ln(\frac{h+l}{h})}$$

Regarding the dimensions it is consistent, but I avoided the problem of having the dx of the integral in the denominator by using sigma. I read that having a dx in the denominator involves doing something wrong and inverting the equation would have given $dP$ in the denominator, which again cannot be solved. Is this a correct procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Pressure is a local property that is captured by the more general concept of [stress tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor). In this case, if you are interested in the pressure at any point $x$ within the given rectangle, you should compute the average pressure on a surface element that is shrinking towards $x$. Assuming that your expression for $F$ is some sort of "cumulative" force, you would compute

$$p(x) = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{F(x+\Delta x)-F(x)}{b\Delta x}=\frac1bF'(x)$$